# Spring ResponseEntity - how to return HTTP 100 Continue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Having rest services using Spring-boot 1.5.8.RELEASE some of the services may take time to process.

My idea is to use HTTP 100 Continue so the response will not time out and then return the final response.

I haven't find any way how to do that

Thanks for any hint